# compilation speed is too slow for a project(about 2000 lines)

Tags: c++, testing, build, compilation

At very first, the code is really simple (less than 500 lines), and complilation can be done within 5 seconds

But **with the growing of codes**, the **compilation** becomes more and more slowly (need about 20 seconds to c, and it will take more time with growing of the code

The files now I have are:

Socket, AsyncSocket, WebsocketHelper, AsyncWebsocketServer, MonitorMessage, HtmlHelper, JsonHelper(abstraction of Jansson library), StringHelper, SqlHelper, Logger, AddLocalServerWindow, LandPointWindow, ServerMonitorProxyDlg

The real problem is that **it takes lots of time to compile every time when I only want to make a little change to project**

e.g.

**I only wanna change a value to test something, it need about 20 seconds to compile**

And then I want to add JsonHelper::buildArray() function, I need at least 2*20 seconds to compile:

when I finish implementing the function, I will compile to see whether it can be compiled correctly, it's the first 20 seconds. Then integrate this method into system and compile, it will take another 20 seconds.
The fact is that every time I written about 5 lines of code, I will compile it to see if there are syntax errors (Is this a bad habbit in such situation?)

Another problem is that I always make syntax mistake in the code(every 10-20 lines), so I need recompile the code again and again. Little compiling time is spent on the code I worte just now(this part is what I really care about), Lots of compiling time is spent on stable code(no error, I wrote before).

How to make this situation better? Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: So is this C# or C++?

Comment: it's c++, but I think c# need compiling as well, so I add c# tag..

Comment: What compiler do you use, build environment, system specs, operating system etc? It is really hard to help you without further detail. If you have a lower end PC it will take time and 20 seconds is not really that much, I have projects that takes way longer than that to compile on a modern PC.

Comment: 2000 lines? 20 seconds? What are you doing, some template black magic (e.g. show the code)? Maybe you should not compile on your mobile phone.

Comment: why are you recompiling unchanged code all the time?

Comment: This question will be nearly impossible to answer. The compile times are not extreme - it's a normal part of programming. We cannot diagnose something without knowing the entirity of your solution. Are you doing a Build or Rebuild each time? How many projects? What is your code complexity? What kind of system are you compiling on?  As far as syntax errors, those should lessen with experience, but no programmer is ever perfect - that's why testing is just as important as the code itself.

Comment: @PederN I'm using VS2010 on windows server 2008, the CPU is Athlon 2.5GHz, memory is 3G

Comment: You know what else might need compiling? C. D. Haskell. Java. Why not add all those tags?

Comment: @hate-engine I only create a simple proxy server based on websocket (and a protocol defined by our company). Several days ago I used boost in the project, it takes more than 40 seconds to compile.. there is no template black magic in the code I wrote, but there are  function to generate sha1, md5 hash and base 64 encoding

Comment: @PlasmaHH any method to not compile unchanged code again and again? I want to do it but don't know how..

Comment: @WonkotheSane yes, I build the project each time. But without building the project, how could I know the code I just wrote is working(or could be compiled correctly)? There is only one project and the code I wrote is really simple.(but there're 3 functions to generate md5, sha1 hash and base64 encoding). Could you give me some suggestions about not building or rebuilding each time? Thanks a lot

Comment: @WonkotheSane sorry, I just think c# is the most popular tag..

Comment: @gbstack: Use _correct_ tags, not _popular_ ones. This is not Amazon.

Comment: in the directory where your solution file is, you are likey to find a .suo file.  get out of visual studio, rename that file to another name, then go back into visual studio.   That file will be recreated.  That may solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# compile time is rarely an issue. The Microsoft C# compiler is very fast compared to the C++ compiler. I work on a large C++ project and here is what we do to mitigate long build times:

- Reduce dependencies. If you only use a pointer or reference to a type within the header file, forward declare the type instead of including.
- Get a faster machine. We develop on 8-core i7's with 16 GB of RAM. This is large enough that the entire source tree fits in the cache. ~135000 lines of code compile in 76 seconds, and this is often more like 10 seconds because only a few files have changed.
- Depending on the application, use a faster compiler. We have the benefit of developing a cross-platform application, so I develop on Linux and use g++, which is several times faster than Microsoft Visual C++. clang is faster yet.
- Spend more time planning your interface. Try not to modify headers too often. One thing that can help with this when used in moderation is the [PIMPL idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom).

Comment: Note that despite the tag, the question actually seems to be about C++

Comment: thanks, it's faster than before after using foward declaration instead of including